# K&R Exercise 3-3: Expand Shorthand Notations (e.g. a-d to abcd)

Tags: c, strings

The following code is my answer for exercise 3-3 in K&R:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000    /* maximum output line size */

int my_getline(char s[], int lim);
void expand(char s1[], char s2[]);

/* Exercise 3-3. Write a function expand(s1,s2) that expands shorthand
    notations like a-z in the string s1 into the equivalent complete list
    abc...xyz in s2. Allow for letters of either case and digits, and be
    prepared to handle cases like a-b-c and a-z0−9 and -a-z. Arrange that a
    leading or trailing - is taken literally. */
main()
{
    char s1[MAXLINE], s2[MAXLINE];

    my_getline(s1, MAXLINE);
    expand(s1, s2);
    printf("Original: %sExpanded: %s", s1, s2);
    return 0;
}

/* getline:  read a line into s, return length */
int my_getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

/* expand:  expand short hand notations in s1 into the equivalent list in s2 */
void expand(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int i, j, k, valid;

    for (i = j = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; ++i, ++j) {
        valid = (islower(s1[i-1]) && islower(s1[i+1]) ||
            isupper(s1[i-1]) && isupper(s1[i+1]) ||
            isdigit(s1[i-1]) && isdigit(s1[i+1])) && s1[i-1] <= s1[i+1];
        if (i != 0 && s1[i+1] != '\0' && s1[i] == '-' && valid) {
            for (k = s1[i-1] + 1; k < s1[i+1]; ++k)
                s2[j++] = k;
            s2[j] = s1[++i];
            if (s1[i+1] != '\0') {
                if (s1[i+1] == '-') /* take trailing - literally */
                    s2[++j] = s1[++i];
            } else
                --j;    /* otherwise j will increment by 2 bypassing '\0' */
        } else
            s2[j] = s1[i];
    }
    s2[j] = '\0';
}
```

Are there any bugs with my approach? Are there ways I could make my code clearer?

Answer (score 16):

I strongly recommend to avoid K&R since it teaches bad style and is very much outdated. This review will focus on general C programming rather than commenting on your specific algorithm.

**Invalid C**

- `main()` is an incorrect signature, this style went obsolete 23 years ago. You must use `int main (void)`.

**Bugs**

- `for (i = j = 0; ...`  then `s1[i-1]`. This accesses `s1` out of bounds at the first lap of the loop.

**Dangerous practice**

- `char s1[MAXLINE], s2[MAXLINE];` it's not a good idea to allocate arrays of thousands of bytes in local scope - these will end up on the stack and eventually you risk stack overflow. Declaring them as `static char s1[MAXLINE]` would have avoided that.
- Incrementing/decrementing loop iterators anywhere else but in the third clause of a `for` loop is poor and dangerous practice, the code turns completely unreadable when you do. You should reconsider writing this loop differently, as close to the idiomatic `for(int i=0; s1[i]!='\0'; i++)` as possible.
- Assignment inside conditions such as `c=getchar()` inside the 2nd `for` clause is bad style. K&R does this a lot but it's universally regarded as bad and bug-prone, why all mainstream compilers force an additional parenthesis when you do.

**Poor style**

- Avoid declaring multiple variables on a single line, it is harder to read and you can get subtle bugs that way too. Instead, declare each variable on a line of its own.
- Loop iterators should be declared inside the for loop clause 1 whenever possible - K&R is completely outdated here. That is `for(int i=0; ...`.
- `s1` isn't modified by the expand function so that function should be written with *const correctness*:
  `void expand (const char s1[], char s2[])`
- `valid` should ideally have been declared as `bool`.

Comment: *"Declaring them as `static char s1[MAXLINE]` would have avoided that"* - and traded an obvious and easily reproduced stack overflow for non-reentrancy, hidden global state, and weird concurrency bugs. Seems like a strange trade.

Comment: @trent This isn't a multi-threaded program so that is irrelevant. Sure you could also put it on the heap but the OP is a beginner so I'm not sure if they know about such yet.

Answer (score 7):

You have run into a well-known trap in the use of the `<ctype.h>` functions (`islower`, `isupper`, `isdigit`).  They take the *unsigned value* of a character rather than `char` (which may be a signed type).  The only negative value accepted is `EOF`.

That means that we need to convert to `unsigned char` before allowing the promotion to `int`.

---

We have invalid access to `s1[-1]` in the first iteration of the loop, when `i` is zero.  The code needs to be modified to avoid that - probably by copying the first character before the loop begins, then starting at `i = 1`.  Remember to check for empty string!

---

There's no test whether we run off the end of `s2` when expanding.  Unfortunately the specified function signature doesn't give us the means to determine that (i.e. the capacity of `s2`).  This can be a real problem when programming in C, and we need to have awareness of this when specifying interfaces.

---

Further exercise:

This can be implemented as a filter without reading a whole line (and therefore not subject to the limit of `MAXLINE`).  Consider what state you need to retain as each character is read.  I think we'll need just a couple of variables (possibly just one, with a little thought), and we can implement this using a small `getchar()/putchar()` loop, with no need for strings.

Comment: In this case there is no reason to suspect that the characters would have values out of range so there is no obvious need to convert to unsigned char either, even though it's good practice.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "out of range".  Negative values of (signed) `char` are very much _in range_ here (and likely on some platforms when ISO 8859 codings are in use).  Just because the range expansion only applies to alphanumeric characters, which are generally positive, doesn't mean that those tests won't be applied to other characters in the string.

Answer (score 5):

I'll focus on the issues of function `expand` which were not already exposed by the other answers.

> Are there any bugs with my approach?

Consider writing automated unit tests to check if the function under development behaves as expected. There are professional-grade open sourced libraries and frameworks dedicated only to this, but for starters, you could just write something like the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void expand(char const *source, char *expanded);
int test_expand(char const *source, char const *expected);

int main(void)
{
    int fails = 0;

    /* "expands shorthand notations like a-z in the string s1 into the
        equivalent complete list abc...xyz in s2."
    */
    fails += test_expand("a", "a");
    fails += test_expand("a-a", "a");
    fails += test_expand("a-z", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

    /* "Allow for letters of either case and digits"
    */
    fails += test_expand("A-F", "ABCDEF");
    fails += test_expand("0-9", "0123456789");

    /* "be prepared to handle cases like a-b-c and a-z0−9"
    */
    fails += test_expand("a-b-c", "abc");
    fails += test_expand("a-z0-9", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789");

    /* "and -a-z. Arrange that a leading or trailing - is taken literally."
    */
    fails += test_expand("-a-z", "-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    fails += test_expand("a-z-", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-");


    if ( fails == 0 )
      puts("So far, so good...");

    return 0;
}

#define BUF_SIZE 100    

int test_expand(char const *source, char const *expected)
{
  char const *row_fmt = "%9s: \"%s\"\n";
  char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
  expand(source, buffer);
  if ( strcmp(expected, buffer) != 0 )
  {
    printf(row_fmt, "FAILED", source);
    printf(row_fmt, "expected", expected);
    printf(row_fmt, "got", buffer);
    putchar('\n');
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

void expand(char const *source, char *expanded)
{
  /* Your implementation */
}
```

Note that a **comment** in your program *describing* the specifications of the function has been transformed into actual **code** checking the *observable behavior* of the function.

If executed, you'll notice that the posted implementation fails multiple tests, like:

```
   FAILED: "0-9"
 expected: "0123456789"
      got: "012345678"

   FAILED: "a-b-c"
 expected: "abc"
      got: "ab-c"
```

Showing both the expected and the actual result helps finding the culprit for the first type of errors (an off-by-one bug), which is the condition in the following line:

```
// ...
      for (k = s1[i-1] + 1; k < s1[i+1]; ++k)
      //                      ^ It should be <=
// ...
```

Just looking at the code, we can spot the other bug, already mentioned in the other answers.

```
// ...
      valid = (islower(s1[i-1]) && islower(s1[i+1]) ||
      //                  ^^^ UB, when i == 0
// ...
```

Other issues are more subtle and require stepping through the code in a debugger.

---

> Are there ways I could make my code clearer?

Consider splitting `expand`:

```
int is_valid_shorthand(char const *source, size_t pos);

void expand(char const *source, char *expanded)
{
  size_t j = 0;
  
  for (size_t i = 0; source[i] != '\0';)
  {
    if ( is_valid_shorthand(source, i) )
    {
      for (char ch = source[i - 1] + 1; ch <= source[i + 1]; ++ch)
      {
        expanded[j] = ch;
        ++j;
      }
      i += 2;
    }
    else
    {
      expanded[j] = source[i];
      ++j;
      ++i;
    }
  }
  expanded[j] = '\0';
}

int is_valid_shorthand(char const *source, size_t pos)
{
  if ( source[i] != '-'  ||  pos == 0  ||  source[pos + 1] == '\0' )
    return 0;

  int const a = (unsigned char)source[pos - 1];
  int const b = (unsigned char)source[pos + 1];
  
  if ( b < a ) // This doesn't allow e.g. "c-a" -> "cba".
    return 0;

  return (isdigit(a) && isdigit(b))
      || (islower(a) && islower(b))
      || (isupper(a) && isupper(b));
}
```

Now it passes all the provided [tests](https://godbolt.org/z/fErafr76f).

Answer (score 3):

**Pedantic corner issues with `my_getline()`**

`if (c == '\n')` accesses uninitialized `c` when `i <= 1`.

`s[i] = '\0';` is *undefined behavior* when `i <= 0`.

`lim-1` is *undefined behavior* when `lim == INT_MIN`.

Consider using `size_t` for array sizing and indexing than `int`.

Repaired code:

```
/* getline:  read a line into s, return length */
size_t my_getline(char s[], size_t lim) {
  int c = 0;
  size_t i;

  for (i=0; i+1 < lim && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i) {
    s[i] = c;
  }
  if (c == '\n') {
    s[i] = c;
    ++i;
  }
  if (lim > 0) {
    s[i] = '\0';
  }
  return i;
}
```

I find `size_t my_getline(size_t lim, char s[])` or `size_t my_getline(size_t lim, char s[lim])` more informative than `size_t my_getline(char s[], size_t lim)`.

Perhaps reform the `for()` loop

```
  size_t length_limit = lim > 0 ? lim - 1 : 0;
  for (i=0; i < length_limit; i++) {
    int c = getchar();
    if (c == EOF) {
      break;
    }
    s[i++] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
      break;
    }
  }
  if (lim > 0) {
    s[i] = '\0';
  }
  return i;
```

- IMO, `my_getline()` should read the entire line, even if it lacks space to save it all.  Return value should then indicate an error.
- When a rare input error occurs, the return value should indicate a failing.
- For those non-2's complement folks out there:  should use `((unsigned char*)s)[i++] = c;` or the like.